# Transporting Pressurized CornyKegs

Tags: kegging, keg, transport

I wanted to get a batch ready for labor day, so I purchased some kegging equipment and opted to keg this beer.  However, I am driving 5ish hours to a lake, where I plan to keep the keg in a ice bath once I get there.  For the transportation:

1.)  Should I keep the CO2 tank hooked up (particularly if its carbed to my liking prior to departure)?  At what PSI?  I realize I will need it once I get there at low PSI to dispense.

2.)  I have no way to keep it cold during the ride, other than some ice packs

3.)  Is it ok to keep the keg on its side during the ride?

4.)  How long should I let it sit once we arrive?

Comment: Regarding Q#1: Are you asking whether you need to keep the CO2 tank hooked up during the car ride (answer: no), or if you need to bring the tank with you and hook it up when you get there (answer: yes, as you dispense beer you need to keep the tank hooked up to keep the beer at the right pressure).

Comment: edited!  and thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.)  no need to keep the tank hooked up.  The keg will retain pressure

2.) No problem

3.) yep.  Just make sure it's tightly sealed!

4.) if there's no sediment in the keg, an hour or 2 will be fine.  Otherwise, maybe overnight

Comment: ice packs should do the job, you can also buy keg parkas to fit over an ice pack. These keep the keg at serving temp for 5 hours.

Comment: one other question, if, by some miracle, the quick carb method worked and my beer is carbonated tonight, will any of the CO2 diffuse out of the keg if I were to keep it pressurized at 50 degrees?  I ask because my fermentation chest is set to 50 to ferment an Octoberfest and it would be easier to stick the keg in there as opposed to changing out ice packs for the next 3 days.

Comment: No CO2 can come out of a sealed keg.  If you chill it, CO2 will migrate from the headspace into the beer more quickly than it would at room temp, but you want the CO2 in the beer anyway!

Comment: right, but I'm asking if the beer temperature increases, will the CO2 migrate from the beer BACK to the headspace?

Comment: Yeah, I think it will to some extent, but it''s dissolve again when you chill it.  I've gone from cold to warm to cold many times and it's never been a problem.  You'll be fine.

Comment: Pietro, If you have a keg of beer at 40 degrees F with 2.5 volumes of CO2 (perfect drinking), and it gets warm (say 70), then CO2 will come out of solution into the headspace and your beer will be "flatter" if served then.  But if you chill it back to 40, it will again have 2.5 volumes CO2 if you give it a chance to equalize.